# Unable to login to sql server

Tags: sql-server

I dont know much about sql server.

I have just re-installed windows 7 on my laptop. After that I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition. I also Installed SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

Now when I try to log in to sql server management studio by using server name as `.` or `(local)` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `PC-Name\SQLEXPRESS` and using `Windows Authentication` I get the error as below.

[image]

Please dont mark this question as negative as I have searched on google for last 4 hours but did not understand the problem.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: It seems your installation was not successful, i would strongly suggest you rather than wasting few more hours here reinstall Management Studio. Please select new installation while installing.

Comment: There is no SQL Server instance installed on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons that may cautioning the problem:

1. SQL Server is not running
2. SQL Server is not properly configured
3. You try to connect with a worng instance Name

You can try the following:

1. Go to Mycomputer->Rigt Click->Manage->Application and Services 
    And from there check that SQL Server Express is running

   2.From there also, gCheck the Instance name of your SQL Express and be sure when you log on to Management Studio you Provide the same Instance name

Comment: I tried no. 1 I go to Services And Application --> Services.  There I cannot find SQL Server

Comment: I have installed sql server management studio and visual studio successfully.

Comment: On the image you updated "Sql Configuration Manager" there is on the left SQL Server Services...Click on that..does it display anything on the right pane?

Comment: That means you havent installed SQL Expess...You have also to install SQl Server Express on your Computer

Comment: ok, I will try to install the sql server management studio again and will come back to you. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: can you suggest me which file should I download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Listen...Management Studio is not the problem..the problem is you havent installed SQL Server...Install SQL Server Express and you will be OK

Comment: can you suggest me which file should I download from http://microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062 I am using 32 bit windows 7

Comment: ENU\x86\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe   (101.5 MB)

Comment: @Khushi 1) Follow these steps to install sql server.http://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-on-windows-7/ 2) Toc check if sql server is installed or not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250480(v=bts.10).aspx 3)Check this also http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Thank you very much. The SQL Server was not installed. I installed it and now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the SQL Server parameters are set accordingly.
Go to Start -

> All Programs — Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 — Configuration tools —
>   SQL Server Configuration Manager

Under SQL Server Services, make sure that the instance is running :

- SQL Server ()
- SQL Server Browser

Under SQL Server Network Configuration - Protocols for (), these are enabled:

- TCP/IP
- Named Pipes

Do the same under SQL Native Client 10.0 under Client Protocols

Comment: Under SQL Server services I dont get anything. I just update the question with image

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the service is installed and running. Under Computer Management, drill-down into Services and Applications -> Services.

There should be a service named "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)". Try a restart or start of the service.

If any other instance of SQL Server is installed it will be listed - try connecting to LOCALHOST(whatever the instance is listed as) to verify the installation is functional.

**UPDATED following further information from comments:**
You may have only installed the client tools (management studio), and have not installed the database service. Ensure you have the correct installer which includes the database services engine.

Comment: The path that you suggested only have 1 service whose name starts with sql. It is SQL Server VSS Writer. I dont find any other services whose name starts with sql

Comment: That suggests your installation didn't finish installing any services. Try running the installation process again and pay particular attention to the screen where you can specify the name of your instance.

Comment: While installing sql server management studio it never asks me to specify the name of the instance.

Comment: When you run the installer and get to the "Installation type" screen, what options do you get? You should try to find the option to install the "database engine services" under "Feature Selection". If you scroll down this page ( http://wiki.octopusnetwork.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26837026) you'll see that you should get to a screen which asks you to specify an instance name